# Terraform EC2 (Root Block device Encryption error failing to reach target state)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

This error has been in the head for over 10 days.

While creating an EC2 Instance in Terraform, the Instance won’t reach the target state and says:

```
Error: Error waiting for instance (i-*************) to become ready: Failed to reach target state. Reason: Client.InternalError: Client error on launch
```

And also we have an encryption of the new EBS Volumes enabled in our EC2 dashboard.

And my basic EC2 Code looks like this:

```
    resource “aws_instance” “web” {
    ami = “ami-"
    instance_type = “t2.micro”
    availability_zone = “ap-south-1a”
    root_block_device {
    volume_size = “10”
    volume_type = “gp2”
    delete_on_termination = true
    encrypted = true
    kms_key_arn = "arn:aws:kms:*************”
    }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you have researched hard enough before asking the question here, as a simple Google search gives this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-client-internal-error/.

Comment: Heyy @Marko E, Since we have our production cluster running on EC2 the new ebs volumes are encrypted. But it's somehow failing to encrypt the Root block device.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been doing this myself.

I'm using KMS CMK and call the arn using:

```
root_block_device {
    kms_key_id    = "arn:aws:kms:*************”
}
```

You may also find that you need to allow the user account in KMS for that CMK, which is usually why you see that error:

```
Error waiting for instance (i-*************) to become ready...
```

Comment: Oh, I see What additional things do you think I am currently missing in that.
Can you please help in this

Comment: Heyyy, what other policies do you this is missing in here.